# Jquery Scroll offset not working on firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, scroll

I have a sticky menubar with smooth scroll that adds a class="active" to the anchor active element.

Here is my js

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    
    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");
        
        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');
      
        var target = this.hash,
        menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        
        if( window.innerWidth > 767 ){
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 53}, 1000, 'swing', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
                $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
            });
        }else{
         $('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top + 1}, 1000, 'swing', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
                $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
            });
        }
    });
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#menu-center a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top - 300 <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#menu-center ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

The offset works perfectly in Chrome and Safari, on mobile and computers but not on firefox and IE. I've been looking for a solution for hours now and can't make it work

Comment: Please make a fiddle [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net) and post it. Be specific and your chance of getting a good answer is much bigger.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? I made [this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7f2o2pd/1/) with your code, and it seems to be working for me on Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Comment: thank you for your answers.

My fixed menubar has a height of 53px. I put the offset at 53px above the target so the menubar doesn't hide the top of my differents sections.

By it doesn't work, I mean that on Firefox and IE, the scroll goes to the good position (offset -53) and jumps to offset0 after +- 200ms

Sorry if I'm not clear, it's hard to explan in english and I'm kind of a noob in js